# AdonisJS installation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I tried to install AdonisJS on Windows 10 according to the tutorial here: https://adonisjs.com/docs/3.2/installation , but I always get the error message:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/: \ at end of pattern
 at C:\Users\...\Desktop\yardstick\app\Listeners\Http.js (C:\Users\...\Desktop\yardstick\app\Listeners\Http.js:1:1)
```

after running `npm run dev`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade the `youch` version to `2.0.4` and it works fine after that.